# How can I exclude some of AWS S3 bucket file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have millions of data in my S3 bucket, Keys are like Id:1, Id:2, Id:3,...........Id1000000.Now thing is that I want to delete all files except Id:5, Id:90, Id:5689. Is it anyway from lifecycle configuration so can we exclude some of the files?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the `aws cli rm` command and using the --exclude filter

Example `aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/ --recursive --exclude "*.jpg"`

For more details see [aws cli rm command details here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html)